# DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain Xcode 10GM

Tags: xcode, xcode10

When I update Xcode to Version 10 GM, build success, but Simulator can't work! with error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain error 0.)

[image]

Comment: I too had similar issue with simulator. Quit simulator and re-run your app worked for me!

Answer (score 105):

run `xcrun simctl erase all` in Terminal. It should solve the issue.
i think its a bug from Apple.

Comment: run this where?

Comment: @Gustavo_fringe on mac Terminal

Comment: It happened to me after I manually deleted the contents of: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ from finder, in order to free up space.  Running the command you mentioned did fix the problem for me, but it recreated all the folders I deleted.  (Not an issue).

Comment: Same bro. Worked like charm

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Not 1 simulator worked and the `UIStoryboard` was not rendering any graphics. The solution was to restart my mac. Not just `Xcode` but your Mac (laptop, mac mini, whatever you might be using)