# Xcode10: The operation couldn't be completed. (DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain error 0.)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, swift4.1

I have tried:

- restart the simulator and Xcode
- delete Xcode and reinstall it
- run **xcrun simctl erase all** this command

I already try but can't solve this issue

[image]

Comment: did you try to run it `xcrun simctl erase all`. Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/52809338/2776008

Comment: i have same issue

Comment: @QuocNguyen it's show this error "An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=164):
Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted"

Comment: Delete all simulators one by one in the Devices and Simulators window. Then create a simulator and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that xcrun is the same installation of Xcode that you're running in the UI:

To check:

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

To change:

```
sudo xcode-select -s {the-path-to}/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this simulator and add it back.I had solved this problem by this way. Maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, Validating the build before distributing it solved the problem.
I forgot to validate before distributing the build.